# Error in catalina log tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

I can start my tomcat, but i can't access my application, after i check my catalina log in my tomcat, show the error below :

```
19-Jul-2017 04:35:17.206 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proj/test]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/proj/test] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [oracle.net.aso.C01->oracle.net.aso.C04->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2054)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2000)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1923)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1163)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5114)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

19-Jul-2017 04:35:17.207 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor /disk/tomcat-instances-8.5.12/my-proj/conf/Catalina/localhost/proj#test.xml
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proj/test]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i already increase my xss memory in startup.sh from "-Xms128m -Xmx768m" to "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m" from error still happen, thanks for the advise

Comment: The error message suggests the `-Xss` argument, did you modify this one ?

Comment: hi, you mean the xss memory i set in startup.sh ?

Comment: Yes, `-Xss` is a VM argument like e.g `-Xmx` and `-Xms`  . See here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Comment: i got set in my startup.sh
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"

Comment: Add something like `-Xss2m` and test  higher values if it fails.